# Random Process not mean square continuous

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

Does a WSS (Wide Sense Stationary) process exist which is not mean square continuous? If so, can you give me an example.

Note: A WSS process is mean square continuous **iff** the autocorrelation function is continuous at 0.

Comment: What about letting all $X_t$ be iid?

Answer (score 0):

One of the basic examples is the so-called *white noise*: Let $(X_t)_{t \geq 0}$ a family of independent and identically distributed square-integrable random variables. Then the autocorrelation function

$$\varrho_X(h) := \frac{\text{cov}(X_t,X_{t+h})}{\sqrt{\mathbb{V}X_t \cdot \mathbb{V}X_{t+h}}}$$

is given by

$$\varrho_X(h) = \begin{cases} 0 & h \neq 0 \\ 1 & h=0 \end{cases}.$$

Obviously, $\varrho_X$ is not continuous at $h=0$.

---

Actually, one can show that for any non-negative definite even function $\gamma: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, $\gamma(0)=1$, there exists a (wide sense stationary) Gaussian process $(X_t)_{t \in \mathbb{R}}$ such that $\gamma$ is the autocorrelation function of $(X_t)_{t \in \mathbb{R}}$. Choosing a functions $\gamma$ which is not continuous at $0$ we obtain a wide sense stationary process which is not mean square continuous.